# laravel 4 auth in route before admin dashboard

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes, authorization, laravel-routing

in my application i have admin dashoboard accessible only to authorized user

in routes.php I have

```
    <?php



Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');

Route::get('detail/{id}', 'HomeController@detail');

Route::get('add', 'HomeController@add');

Route::post('create', 'HomeController@create');

Route::get('login', 'SessionController@create');

Route::get('logout', 'SessionController@destroy');

Route::resource('sessions', 'SessionController');

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::get('admin/delete/{id}', 'AdminController@delete');
    Route::get('admin/edit/{id}', 'AdminController@edit');
    Route::get('admin/state/{id}', 'AdminController@state');
    Route::post('admin/update/{id}', 'AdminController@update');
});


Route::get('o_nas', 'AboutController@index');


View::composer('layouts.partials.categories', function($view)
{
    $view->categories = Category::all();
});
```

but if I try admin/edit/2 without login, the page is accessible. Why the before 'auth' is not function in my example

in app/filters.php is

```
    Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

Comment: you should show your `auth` filter. Is this page accessible when you simple put url `admin/edit/2` in browser without sending any form?

Comment: i edit post to add auth filter. Yes this page is accessible with url admin/edit/2 without sending login form

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code in fresh project and there is no error here. The only possibility is that you have defined your `auth` filter more than once, for example if you had defined your filter like this:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{

});

// any other actions

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

than your filter won't work as expected because it seems the first filter will work. In other case everything works as expected - you can create one fresh project with those `routes.php`, your filter and creating just `SessionController` and you will see that `http://localhost/testproject/admin/edit/2` will redirect you to `http://localhost/testproject/login`

Comment: maybe the problem is that AdminControllers is in controllers/admin directory

Comment: @mardon Maybe however I don't think so. But just in case you can edit your question and at it's content to your question